# Redirect using JSON Response in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to redirect using return data in JSON but it's now working. It's easy to do it in JavaScript using location.href but in Laravel Controller nothing happens. I have something like this.

```
        if(count($modelData) > 0) {
            $status = 'info';
            $message = 'Logged Out Successfully';
        } else {
            $status = 'error';
            $message = 'User Not Found';
        }

        $returnData = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
            'redirect' => '/visitor-logs'
        );

        return response()->json($returnData);
```

Comment: You are just returning json so the redirect has to be initiated by the client. This is just a json object with a redirect key

Answer (score 1):

When you want to return something like json from a certain request, that's what you get, just a json response. It doesn't make much sense that you generate a re-direct from the controller script itself.

So, whatever re-direction action hapenning, will be happening on the client side in this case. This means on the code executing on the browser and not in the server.

With that json response, in the client, with javascript you can generate a redirection with `location.href` using the value from `response.redirect`.

Note: As a Note I must clarify that you can generate redirects on the server side, of course. But it's not the case here.

Comment: In my case, blade -> a custom crudjs that already has the response -> controller -> override that response. I can't get back to the client.

Comment: You say you are using a custom crudjs something that is supposed to handle the redirect automatically. Maybe something wrong is happening with that crudjs. I would check on the brower's dev tools console and see if some error is being triggered there.